# Poincare Inequality in n-dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to prove the Poincare Inequality on a n-dimensional box. That is a domain $ \Omega = (0,1)^n$ for $f(x) \epsilon H^{1}_{0}(\Omega) $, show there exists a constant $C$ such that $||f||_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C||\nabla f||_{L^{2}(\Omega)} $ . I am not sure how to proceed.

Can I use the Divergence theorem here? How about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?